# Autolayout margins between buttons are incorrect only on 4" screen

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a bunch of views that look perfect on a 3.5 inch screen. When I test it on the iPhone 5 simulator, which has a 4 inch screen, the padding between the buttons is way off.

It is not just for this view, and the padding problem always seems to happen at certain spots (for example, after 2 buttons). I assume this has to do with the new feature of constraints for iOS 6. and I have tried messing around with the values with no luck. I am doing everything in IB and autolayout is enabled.

Can anyone explain to me what I must do?

3.5 Inch screen iPhone 4 looks good!     4 Inch screen iPhone 5 margin is off.

[image: 3.5 Inch screen iPhone 4 looks good!] [image: 4 Inch screen iPhone 5 margin is off]

Comment: did you use autolayout feature?

Comment: @iiFreeman If by use, you mean check the box for the "use autolayout" option in IB, then yes. Is this what you meant? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IB pins views to the closest edge of their superview; in your case the top two buttons are pinned to the top and the bottom two are pinned to the bottom. When the view is stretched to fit the 4 inch screen, they separate.

Use the pinning menu to explicitly create the constraints you require (probably to pin the spacing between all the buttons), then delete the constraints pinning your buttons to the bottom of the superview.

I have written more about this topic (including a discussion of your exact case) [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/) if you want a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to get it work even after your tutorial. I apologize, I must be retarded. For example, in IB, I grabbed test3 button and I messed with the "bottom space to" constraint with no effect. Then I tried the "align leading to test2" in hopes of something... no luck. Any other suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: btw should my size of the view be set to retina 3.5 full screen or 4.0? perhaps this is the issue

Comment: Leading space is the space to the left, you want top space, or vertical space - select button 3 and choose pin top space to super view from the pinning menu. Only then will you be allowed to delete the bottom space constraint. To pin two buttons together, select them _both_ then choose pin vertical spacing.